# Why is IIFE required in the following context?

Tags: javascript

I am working to emulate the `require` functionality with a few javascript functions, for example:

```js
// We set up an object that will include all the public modules
// And then a require function which basically just accesses that public module
const modules = {};
function require(moduleName) {
    return modules[moduleName];
}
modules['math.js'] = function() {
    // hidden implementation details
    let incr = x => ++x;
    return {
        incr, 
        sum(x,y) { return x+y; }
    }
}
```

Why is it required to do `modules['math.js'] = (function() {...})();` and not just a normal non-invoked function call as above?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`modules["match.js"]` is only a function. You probably want it to be an object:

```
modules["math.js"] = { ... };
```

But then you won't have private members or functions you can use! Everything will be public. So to solve this we create a closure:

```
modules["math.js"] = function () {
    let priv = 0;

    return { ... };
};
```

Here's where we are now. To make it a closure AND have `modules["math.js"]` be a nice object we can use, we immediately call this function:

```
modules["math.js"] = (function () {
    let priv = 0;

    return { ... };
})();
```

Now, `modules["math.js"]` is an object with members and methods we can use, AND it has a private locally scoped variable named `priv` that can be used only by the module.

This is similar to ES6 modules where you export a select few values bound to identifiers and everything else in the file is private.

Comment: I see, so calling the function immediately basically "skips" returning the function and instead returns the object returned by the function (or whatever the function returns, but it's almost always going to be an object). Is that correct?

Comment: If by "return" you mean "evaluate to", then yes! You don't want the function itself, you only want the object returned by it. The function only serves as a closure for private members.